# How to create a SQLAlchemy model instance with a tuple or dict fetched with MySQLdb?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What can I do to turn the following tuple

`(1, u'1842951147', u'Proin velit hac duis class torquent vestibulum phasellus velit erat ligula rhoncus habitasse per nulla. Purus neque. Netus felis. Fusce justo est amet pede pharetra fermen', u'Cabo HDMI 1.3 1080P, 3 entradas')`

into a model instance managed by SQLAlchemy?

Assume that the `id` of the record above is `1`, if an instance corresponding to this `id` already exist, we need to update it with this new found record.

Comment: I think `Session.merge` is what you're looking for: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.merge

Comment: @sebastian I've tried using `Session.merge` to include an instance created with a raw `dict`, but it resulted in a `FlushError` saying the instance conflicts with persistent instance when I tried to update and commit.